# How to add a file to joomla with db connectivity

Tags: php, joomla, module, die

I have added a new file for Joomla called `search.php` which I need for my custom module,
but that can be accessible through the browser URL. If I type the file path, all code is visible, I want to stop that.

When I use `defined('_JEXEC') or die;` module is not working properly. Please advise where I have gone wrong.

```
 <?php
//define('_JEXEC', 1);
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('JPATH_BASE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DS . '');
require_once (JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php');
require_once (JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php');
require_once (JPATH_BASE . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'joomla' . DS . 'factory.php');

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$searchc=$_GET["term"];
$searchc = str_replace(' ', '', $searchc);
$query = $db -> getQuery(true);
```

**UPDATE**

```
    define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );//this is when we are in the root
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
```

when i use updated code its work , but how to change JPATH base to access my file which inside  module directory . please advice

Comment: What happens if you remove `defined('_JEXEC') or die;` and use  `define('_JEXEC', 1);`?

Comment: @Lodder :: then its accessible through browser : Ex: localhost/modules/search/search.php  if i type this on browser it showing the json output which generate form this file. i want to hide it. and display 'restricted access' kind of thing or blank page

Comment: @Lodder : please check my updated code and advice me how to porceed with JPath BASe

Comment: Can you give the exact path of your file, for example >> `modules/mod_search/search.php`

Comment: @Lodder : here it is :  modules/mod_search/tmpl/search.php

Comment: @Lodder : file path : modules/mod_search/tmpl/search.php  please advice how would i put pase path for this with dirname(__FILE__)

Comment: So the problem is that you want to return the json when the context is where you want it, but not directly? Maybe check the JInput for the context and if it's wrong then return? It's a little hard without knowing where you are getting it from or how you are getting the json.